# Is it possible to pass any object as a parameter to LinkButton.CommandArgument using markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webcontrol

There is information on MSDN which says that CommandEventArgs.CommandArgument returns object which could be casted to particular type. There is example there. So is it possible to pass View for example?

The example on MSDN has string as parameter. It's pretty clear with string anf integer types:

```
Markup: CommandArgument="some_string_to_path"
CodeBehind: (string)e.CommandArgument
```

I wonder if I can pass View to show in MultiView on Render event.

```
Markup: CommandArgument=<% someView %>
```

I've decided to try on my own and got: server tag cannot contain <% ... %>.

So is it possible to pass any object I want or there are some restrictions?

Comment: `CommandArgument='<%# someView %>'`

Comment: You can set this in the codebehind.